# Use flex 3 module from Javascript

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, module

Is there a way to call flex module from Javascript?

The context: I'm running flex app with embedded HTML/Javascript, and I have to call flex module from this app from Javascript.

Maybe I have to make the module standalone?

I also found this approach with ExternalInterface:
http://www.flexafterdark.com/docs/Flex-JavaScript

Is that the solution? Expose a callback which loads and opens the module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExternalInterface is the way to do it.

If all you want to do is load and open the module, just use `ExternalInterface.addCallback` to create a callback to a function that loads and opens the module as you would normally.

If you need to be able to call functions on the module after it's loaded, for every method you want to be able to use from JavaScript, you can use `ExternalInterface.addCallback` to register it.  Or you can get fancy and use `describeType` to get all the public methods of the module, and register them in a loop, rather than specifying them one by one.

Keep in mind that you can't pass complex objects over the ExternalInterface.  Typed JS objects become generic { } objects.  Functions become null.